# how can I put two rows side by side

Tags: html, css

I have 2 rows of 4 columns each,
I want a certain size range to be 3 rows
The problem is that in the current code
The lines are not connected together, how to solve it?

THIS IS THE CSS CODE

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

   .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

   .wrapper > * {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex: 0 1 25%;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
   .wrapper>* {
     flex: 0 1 33.33%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

How to combine 2 divs so that they fit together?
It currently looks like this:

```
1 2 3 
4
5 6 7 
8
```

I want it to be so, with the 2 divs above

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8
```

Comment: Please put [executable scripts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) when using Javascript, HTML or CSS.

Answer (score -1):

change html structure is the simplest method.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
 <div>7</div>
 <div>8</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper .div{ float: left; width: 33.3%; }
</style>
```